# how to operate None in the list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make [2,3,None,4,None] into [4,6,None,8,None],how can i do?

```
>>> v= [2,3,None,4,None]
>>> [x*2 for x in v if not x is None]
[4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Just add an `else` clause to include the Nones:

```
>>> [x*2 if x is not None else x for x in v]
[4, 6, None, 8, None]
```

Note that you must put the `if-else` *before* the `for x in v`; otherwise you'd get a syntax error.

Personally, I'd rewrite it a little further to make the behavior more explicit, but it's all up to you.

```
>>> [None if x is None else x*2 for x in v]
[4, 6, None, 8, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use NaN instead of `None`, you can simplify your code, since NaN already behaves in the desired way, i.e. `2*nan` evaluates to `nan` again, so you don't need to special-case it:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> v = [2, 3, nan, 4, nan]
>>> [2 * x for x in v]
[4, 6, nan, 8, nan]
```